# Why isn't react navigation working in react native?

Tags: react-native

I tried "npm install --save react-navigation"
and got a bunch of errors:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hoppe\rn-meal-app\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\hoppe\rn-meal-app\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\hoppe\rn-meal-app\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics' -> 'C:\Users\hoppe\rn-meal-app\node_modules@react-navigation\core\node_modules.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hoppe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-30T02_38_23_800Z-debug.log

Comment: Make you've read the installation instructions described in the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

For Install --react-navigation-- you need install some package dependencies like :

- react-native-reanimated
- react-native-gesture-handler
- react-native-screens
- react-native-safe-area-context
- @react-native-community/masked-view

you can install that with this:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

for more read see that [Link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)